# Developing a multistep form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, form

I implemented a multistep form with the method described by Ryan Bates in [ep217](http://www.asciicasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) but I had some weird behavior when refreshing or moving between the steps [Acts_as_good_style](http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2007/08/actsasgoodstyle.html) (old but still good) has a tip **redirect when moving on** that lead me to the change in the code that follows.

In a nutshell, it says that if you're in the `create` action you should not render `new` (as I was doing).

This solved the problem. But I had to manage the case of errors in the form, so I ended up with this code.

```
#profiles_controller.rb

def create
  # [...] save etc [...]

  # render
  if @profile.new_record?  
    # render 'new' # OLD
    session[:profile_valid] = @profile.errors.blank?  # NEW
    redirect_to new_profile_path # NEW
  else 
    # [...]
  end
end 


def new  
  @profile = Profile.new(session[:profile_params])  
  # [...]

  # rebuild errors (see create)
  # check false because first time is nil and no error have to be displayed
  @profile.valid? if session[:profile_valid] == false
  session[:profile_valid] = true
end
```

Where in the `new` action I reload the errors otherwise lost depending on `session[:profile_valid]`, that works fine.

BUT this way doesn't look very good to me and I would appreciate to have your opinion, OR how do you manage your controllers in multispets forms?

What was the strange behavior? Refreshing or going back and forth through the steps sometimes you jump to the wrong page, not clear what the logic is, probably depends on the validations in the model and the params hash.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for that particular Railscast episode, but rails provides an idiomatic way to deal with validation errors. Taking your code as an example, I'd change it to look like this (using Rails 4.2):

**app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:**

```
class ProfilesController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @profile = Profile.find(...)
  end

  def new  
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile)

    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @profile = Profile.find(...)
  end

  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(...)

    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile)

    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def profile_params
    # call params.require(:profile).permit(...) to whitelist attributes as needed
    params.require(:profile)
  end
end
```

**app/views/profiles/new.html.haml:**

```
%h2 New Profile
= render partial: 'form'
```

**app/views/profiles/edit.html.haml:**

```
%h2 Edit Profile
= render partial: 'form'
```

**app/views/profiles/_form.html.haml:**

```
= form_for(@profile) do |f|
  - # Display any form errors, if any
  - if @profile.errors.any?
    .errors
      %h2 Errors
      %ul
        - @profile.errors.full_messages do |message|
          %li= message

  - # Assuming profiles have first_name and last_name as attributes
  %section
    = f.label :first_name
    = f.text_field :first_name

  %section
    = f.label :last_name
    = f.text_field :first_name

  %section
    = f.submit
```

This is a very common pattern in rails apps that you can also see being used in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects). The `form_for` helper is smart enough to generate the correct path to submit the form to depending on weather or not the `@profile` instance variable contains a record that has or has not been persisted. Persisted records (new ones or those with errors) will be posted to create. Records being updated will be set to whatever the `update` action/path for that controller is.

Whenever updating or saving a record fails, the controller will render the appropriate view (`new` or `edit`) and use the record that failed validation when rendering the form. From here, your view can inspect the record and display any errors if they exist (`@profile.errors`).

This won't fix an issue of a user navigating backwards and forwards through your form, but it should reduce the need to do so and it'll let you avoid weirdness you may have encountered while persisting form data within the `session` variable (which gets serialized and de-serialized into whatever your session store is during each request).

---

PS: I find that thinking of multi-step forms with more than one or two steps as [state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) helps greatly in trying to conceptualize the different states and transitions you need to handle when you need to determine at what point in a form a particular session should be in. To that effect, I would highly recommend checking out the [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked) gem which does a lot of this grunt work for you.

Comment: I like your answer! I'll wait a day or two before granting the bounty. Thanks for looking it over!

Comment: Thanks. Relatively simple question though, I'm surprised nobody has chimed in yet.